# Count list elements without duplicates

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to Python and finding my way.

I have this code here:

```
L = ['l','u','k','e','l','i'] 
k = [L.count(c) for c in L]
print(k)
```

And it gives this result:

```
[2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
```

which is great but I want to get to this result

```
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

That is, a result in which the 'l' is not counted twice. 
How do I do that?

NB: the list L here is from user input, I convert user input to list L so I can't tell beforehand what the user will input but once its typed in, I want to convert the string into a list and count all the elements without counting an element twice.

Comment: You can use `set` which will give you a unique list of elements from your list `k = [L.count(c) for c in set(L)]`

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like that

```
L = ['l','u','k','e','l','i'] 
import collections
s = collections.Counter(L)
s
Counter({'l': 2, 'u': 1, 'k': 1, 'e': 1, 'i': 1})
s.values()                  
dict_values([2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: this is just an example, I intend to get the items in L from user input and cannot tell what will be put in there. L is created by converting a string from user input into a list

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary:

```
L = ['l','u','k','e','l','i']
counts = {}

for l in L:
    counts[l] = counts.get(l, 0) + 1

print(counts)
# {'k': 1, 'l': 2, 'e': 1, 'u': 1, 'i': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works!:  L = ['l','u','k','e','l','i']
D = {}
for char in L:
    D[char] = D.get(char, 0)+1
    Countslist = [D[key] for key in D]
print(Countslist)